# Adding specific bindings in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I have a class with the following constructor

```
 public BiddingTierSetViewModelValidator(
            IPropertyValidator allTiersMustBeContiguous,
            IPropertyValidator firstItemMustHaveZeroStartValue,
            IPropertyValidator lastItemMustHaveNullEndValue,
            IPropertyValidator allExceptLastItemMustHaveNonNullEndValue,
            IPropertyValidator biddingTierViewModelValuesCorrect)
```

When I run the application I get this error

```
Missing dependency.
Component <namespace>.BiddingTierSetViewModelValidator has a dependency on FluentValidation.Validators.IPropertyValidator, which could not be resolved.
Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in the container as a service, or provided as inline argument.
```

What I want to be able to do is for each of these `IPropertyValidator` parameters I want to pass in a different implementation.  How do I set this up in Windsor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change te constructor to:

```
public BiddingTierSetViewModelValidator(IPropertyValidator [] propertyValidators)
```

Register all the validators in the container and add the following:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver());
```

Good luck,
Marwijn.